# How can i insert a single data into a Mysql table using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have tried this code but i receive the 1064 error.

```
x_1=**********    
t_2=(x_1)
cursor.execute('insert into informations' '(password)' 'values (%s)',t_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.execute('insert into informations (password) values (?)', (x_1,))
```

would be a better syntax.

Just one string including the whole statement and using a question mark as placeholder for the value to insert.

The most important is to define the single value into a tuple.